# Creating a Class from 3 different EntitySet

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, iqueryable

Since I am using the following query too much I have decided to create a class and a function which returns some of the attributes from three tables as follows;

```
public class EntityHandler
{
    public IQueryable<Entity.MedicalEntities> GetAll(Entity.MedicalEntities Entity)
    {
        IQueryable<Entity.MedicalEntities>  result = from mID in Entity.Medicals
                     join cs in Entity.Cities on mID.CityFK equals cs.CityID
                     join reg in Entity.Regions on cs.RegionFK equals reg.RegionID

                     select new
                     {
                         medicalName = mID.medicalName,
                         MedicalID = mID.MedicalID,
                         CityName = cs.CityName,
                         CityID = cs.CityID,
                         RegionName = reg.RegionName,
                         RegionID = reg.RegionID
                     };

        return result;
    }
}
```

But I get the following error;

```
Error1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' 
to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MedicalBootStrap.Entity.MedicalEntities>'. An explicit
conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Do you have any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating an object of type `Entity.MedicalEntities`. So you need to change the select statement from returning an anonymous type to a strongly typed entity.

```
public IQueryable<Entity.MedicalEntities> GetAll(Entity.MedicalEntities Entity)
{
    IQueryable<Entity.MedicalEntities>  result = from mID in Entity.Medicals
                 join cs in Entity.Cities on mID.CityFK equals cs.CityID
                 join reg in Entity.Regions on cs.RegionFK equals reg.RegionID

                 //insert actual real entity name for Entity.MedicalEntity
                 select new Entity.MedicalEntity
                 {
                     medicalName = mID.medicalName,
                     MedicalID = mID.MedicalID,
                     CityName = cs.CityName,
                     CityID = cs.CityID,
                     RegionName = reg.RegionName,
                     RegionID = reg.RegionID
                 };

    return result;
}
```

**//EDIT**
I think you forgot some information in your question, like the three original tables and the class you created. I just assumed the 3 tables are `Medicals` `Cities` & `Regions` and
`MedicalEntities` represents the ViewModel you have created out of it.

Comment: yes you are right, since MedicalEntities a viewmodel it throws an error as; medicalName (and all other atttributes) does not contain a definition for medicalName I guess